# How to reload item's view controller in tab bar on click of reload/reset button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to reload only selected view controller in tab bar controller on click of reset button as you can see in below image.

I tried many couple of line code, but they never worked for me. How can I reload view controller on button click.

```
@IBAction func reset_Btn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reset", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as? UITabBarController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
        
        
    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
          
    }))

    present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
    
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: reset is in Navigation Bar ?

Comment: No it's in a view which I use as Navigation Bar,

Comment: you used that view as nav bar in each view ?

Comment: No, it depends on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need reload your viewcontroller?

just reset all variable to nil or if you are using array just `.removeAll()`
and reload your tableView

why? well, if you use this

```
  let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as? UITabBarController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
```

it'll not reload your viewcontroller instead it'll make a new controller, your previous controller wouldn't dissapear at least if you dont remove them from stack controllers

and

pushViewController using navigation controller wouldnt work, I assume your root view controller is UITabbarViewController,

if you still wanna push them just try this

```
self.tabBarController?.show(<#T##vc: UIViewController##UIViewController#>, sender: <#T##Any?#>)
```

just remember what i said above,